# How do I trigger on blur and run through all inputs in a row?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with a trigger in jQuery. It triggers too many times.

I have a table with 11 inputs per row. I need the script to trigger a blur once per input in the row I left, when I change row.

My main event handlers looks like this:

```
$('#auto_insert').on('blur', 'input.autoupdate', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    rid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    row_validate(rid);
});
$('#auto_insert').on('focus', 'input.autoupdate', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    newid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    check();
});
```

The function `row_validate` is used for validating and needs to run through all the inputs in a row:

```
function row_validate(rid) {
    $('#auto_insert #' + rid + ' td input.autoupdate').each(function () {
        $(this).trigger('blur');
    });
}
```

Any suggestions as to why it won't work?

It mostly does what it should, but it keeps looping and I'm unsure why.

New info:

It seems like its a massibe bubbeling effect that makes my validation run out of control.
is there a way to prevent it bubbling past my tr?

Comment: Can you post the HTML as well?  Your $(this).trigger('blur') is most likely causing an infinite loop of blur events.

Comment: So you're calling row_validate(rid) from your 'onblur' event, which calls 'onblur' internally? Isn't this a loop?

Comment: Why 2 different IDs in your selector in `row_validate`? I guess you should remove `#auto_insert`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the handler for the `blur` event calls `row_validate()` which triggers a `blur` event for every cell -> endless loop.

What you need to do is to move validation into a new function which only validates. Then call this new function from the blur handler (single cell change) and from the `row_validate()` function (row change).

The validate function itself must not trigger any events!!